# redis.exceptions.ResponseError: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots

Tags: redis

I'm with this problem when I try to save to redis. Introducing the message below.

MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it's currently unable to persist to disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled, because this instance is configured to report errors during writes if RDB snapshotting fails (stop-writes-on-bgsave-error option). Please check the Red

The redis log file displays this:

Background saving started by pid 73
Write error saving DB on disk: Function not implemented

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, would be great if you just post it as answer and select is as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. You need to wsl 2 To find out the version run below command in PowerShell

wsl -l -v
If it is version 1, run the command below and open ubuntu again

wsl --set-version  2
More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, here's how I fixed the issue when it seemed that Redis didn't have permission to write its snapshots.

```
cd /usr/local/var/db
sudo chown -R [username] db
brew services stop redis
brew services start redis
```

[Reference](https://gist.github.com/kapkaev/4619127?permalink_comment_id=3805131#gistcomment-3805131)